# Apparently inexplicable packet-loss; possibly causing slow Skype connection despite speed-tests showing good up and downstream speeds at both ends

Tags: command-line, ip, sniffing, packet-loss, packet-injection

I have done a look Whois lookup on my IP Address which is returning [redacted by instruction]. We're currently connected via Skype so I know transmissions are sending; however, when my friend attempts to ping my computer typing the exact same IP Address the console shows `Request timed out`.

Comment: I can't even tell what you are asking here. What exactly do you want to know? Please [edit] your question to add an actual *question*.

Comment: I'm saying my friend pinged my computer and got 100% packet loss but we are connected to Skype so how the hell can he not be able to ping me?

Comment: @Lene'A'Anderson - Because your friend is connected to Skype, communicating with you through Skype, and does not need any connection to your computer to do so.  Skype no longer, and has not, used a Peer 2 Peer connection for several years now.  Microsoft even went as far to completely obfuscate user's ip addresses recently.  The obfuscation only applies to newer versions of Skype though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your computers IP address public? A whois lookup will give you your routers IP address.

Because Skype and ping use different protocols and ports. It is entirely possible for a computer or router that is up and on the network to refuse to reply to ping requests. Usually non-server computers won't answer a ping, because it tells everyone that the computer is alive and out there, so they can then try other nasty stuff with it (i.e a computer that answers a ping is an invitation to potential hackers).
Its also possible that your firewall or router is blocking the ping request or response.

Before you open your computer up to reply to pings, ensure you have secured it against every possible hack out there. Good luck!

Comment: So... my IP is 77.234.43.185. Is 77.234.43.185 a public IP address?

Comment: yes, it is a public IP address owned by Avast.http://whois.domaintools.com/77.234.43.185